# How to grab the difference between two CSV files in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

How do I calculate the difference between two CSV files:

So the final dataframe should look like this:

many thanks!

Comment: You could use `abs(df1_value - df2_value)` to get the difference between the numbers.

Comment: @SamMatzko that assumes that both frames status columns are in the same order and identical. Probably better to merge and take the difference.

Comment: @It_is_Chris What would be the command for taking the diff? Thanks

Comment: @It_is_Chris. Another way is to use `Status` columns as index rather than `merge` because you will create 2 `Count` columns (Count_x, Count_y).

Comment: @khordi `df1.merge(df2, on='Status').set_index('Status').diff(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Status` columns as index to align index between the 2 dataframes then apply operations `sub` and `abs`. Finally, reset index to get original format.

Input data:

```
>>> df1
          Status  Count
0        Backlog     23
1  Investigation     27

>>> df2
          Status  Count
0  Investigation     25
1        Backlog     24
```

Output result:

```
>>> df1.set_index('Status')['Count'] \
       .sub(df2.set_index('Status')['Count']) \
       .abs().reset_index()

          Status  Count
0        Backlog      1
1  Investigation      2
```

Comment: BINGO! This worked flawlessly, thanks so much. Could you explain what this is doing if you dont mind?

Comment: Perfect, thanks for this! you are a hero :)

Comment: Glad to help! Thank you so much for your support :)

Answer (score 2):

If you set the index to the `Status` column on both dataframes, you can subtract one from the other, then take the absolute value of the result.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Status': ['Backlog', 'Investigation', 'Implementation',
                               'On Hold', 'Verification', 'Done', 'Not a Problem'],
                    'Count': [23, 27, 10, 18, 85, 225, 82]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Status': ['Backlog', 'Investigation', 'Implementation',
                               'On Hold', 'Verification', 'Done', 'Not a Problem'],
                    'Count': [24, 25, 10, 18, 85, 224, 82]})
df3 = (df1.set_index('Status') - df2.set_index('Status')).abs()
print(df3)
```

You can also use the [`sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) function that has one advantage. If you have missing values in either dataframe, or the indexes don't match exactly (as they do in your example), you can give it a fill value to use as a placeholder.

```
df4 = df1.set_index('Status').sub(df2.set_index('Status'), fill_value=0).abs()
print(df4)
```

**Note:** If you load the dataframes from CSV files using [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), you can set the index column at the same time.

```
df1 = pd.csv_read('path/to/file.csv', index_col='Status')
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I also tried this solution and it works too. thanks for your time.